# Why increase in enthalpy leads to increase in entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics, enthalpy, entropy, adsorption

Given statement: Enthalpy of adsorption is the strength at which molecule (say $\ce{H2}$) is bound to the adsorbent (say some metal center). For a free $\ce{H2}$ molecule, the entropy contribution is from translational, rotational and vibrational motion. After the adsorption, the translational and rotational motions will not contribute to the entropy change $\mathrm{\Delta S}$. Thus the only contribution to $\mathrm{\Delta S}$ is from the vibrational motion of $\ce{H2}$ which will decrease for increase in adsorption strength.

As per the given statement, increase in enthalpy should decrease the entropy. However, [Enthalpy-Entropy correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy%E2%80%93entropy_compensation) states that increase in enthalpy leads to increase in entropy. How this is true?

Comment: Could you explain why you think that the enthalpy increases? Isn't the absorption exothermic as, for instance, stated [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150329a001) (--> decrease of enthalpy) ?

Comment: Why, recalling  the change of Free / Gibbs enthalpy expressed as $\Delta{}_R G = \Delta_RH - T\Delta_RS$, both changes of enthalpy *and* of  entropy (multiplied by  temperature) are taken into consideration?  Currently your question reads like one were enough, which I doubt.